# Trying to check and send mysql info

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

```
<script>
function buttonClick(){
   var total = 0;
   var type = "";
   for(var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
     var id = "max_clicks" + i;
     var label = "label" + i;
     var badge = "badge" + i;
     if (document.getElementById(id).checked!=null && document.getElementById(id).checked==true) {
        total += parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
        type +="Max-clicks:<hr style='margin-top:-1px;' />"+ "<span class='badge' style='margin-top:-5px;'>" + document.getElementById("label"+i).innerHTML + "</span> : <span class='badge' style='margin-top:-5px;'>" + document.getElementById("badge"+i).innerHTML + "</span><br />";
      }
   }

  document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById('individual').innerHTML = type;
}
</script>

<form action="<?php echo "".site_url."";?>/magaza/reklam-ver" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="checkbox" name="max_clicks[]" id="max_clicks1" value="<?php echo "".$price1."";?>" onClick="buttonClick(this);">
    <label id="label1" class="badge" style="background:#fc5a5d;"> 150 clicks</label>-<span class="badge" id="badge1">Price: 5 credits</span><br />


    <input type="checkbox" name="max_clicks[]" id="max_clicks2" value="<?php echo "".$price2."";?>" onClick="buttonClick(this);">
    <label id="label2" class="badge" style="background:#fc5a5d;"> 400 clicks</label>-<span class="badge" id="badge2">Price: 13 credits</span><br />



    <input type="checkbox" name="max_clicks[]" id="max_clicks3" value="<?php echo "".$price3."";?>" onClick="buttonClick(this);">
    <label id="label3" class="badge" style="background:#fc5a5d;"> 735 clicks</label>-<span class="badge" id="badge3">Price: 9 credits</span><br />


    <span id="individual" class="badge" style="background:#f29d9d;">You dont have any select item.</span>

    <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary" onclick="buttonClick()">Price to pay: 
    <span class="badge"><span id="Totalcost">0</span> credits</span></button>

<input  class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;" type="submit" name="add_ad" value="Reklam satın al">
</form>
```

I trying to get checked item and send to mysql... All working but have problem with send to mysql i want to send max-click -info of `<span>`....`</span>` and check price with input value and send this to mysql - max-clicks -value off `<span>`..`</span>` and value of input any ideas ? i give my script form.php and action_form.php and sorry for my language :/

```
if($_POST['add_ad'])
{  
    if(!empty($_POST['max_clicks'])) {
        $shipping_subtotal = 0;
        foreach($_POST['max_clicks'] as $shipping){
            $shipping_subtotal += $shipping;
        }
        $user = userInfo();
        if($user['credits'] >= $shipping_subtotal){ //check user have enough credits or not  
             if($_POST['title'] && $_POST['target_url'])
              {
                $expires = strtotime("+1 month"); //Reklam 1 ay ekle
                $title = quote_smart($_POST['title']);
                $target_url = quote_smart($_POST['target_url']);
               mysql_query("INSERT INTO ads (date_added,date_expires, target_url, clicks, author_id, title, max_clicks) VALUES ('".time()."',$expires, $target_url, '0', '".$_COOKIE['user_id']."', $title, $shipping_subtotal)") or die(mysql_error());
               echo info("Success!");
               delcredits($user['id'], $shipping_subtotal);
               header ("refresh:3;url=".site_url."/magaza/reklam-ver");
              }
              else
              {
                echo error("Error.");
              }
              }
              else
              {
                echo error("you dont have enough credits");
              }
    }
    else{
        echo "<b>Please select max-clicks.</b>";
    }

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are your values making it to the post? Do you successfully connect to sql? Does sql throw any errors?

Comment: i dont have error only wrong working script ... i want send to mysql 
max-clicks - and price 
but my script send to mysql max-clicks=price .... if you no understand text ..

Comment: you need to send the price to another variable instead of `max-clicks`

Comment: I know how i get this price value of cheked box .. i not use input to set value"price" i use <span> and i need to send this span content to sql max-click  and input content to sql price